# How to close mySql query connection in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-connector, node-mysql

I am using raw mySql query for my development.
I want to close the query connection after executing the query.
What can I use as per my code?

**My Connection Sample:**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const sequelize =
  new Sequelize(process.env.DBNAME, process.env.DBUSER, process.env.DBPASS,
    {
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.HOST_PORT,
      dialect: 'mysql',
      operatorsAliases: 0,
      timezone: "+06:00",

      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
      }
    }
  )

module.exports = sequelize;
```

**My Query sample:**

```
const dbConnect = require('../database/db');

let getEmployeeData = 
      await dbConnect.query(
                  `Select * From employee where employeeId = '00001'`, 
                  {type: QueryTypes.SELECT});

return res.json({data: getEmployeeData});
```

**Before return I want to close my query connection. As I am getting error "packets_out_of_order" after idle the connection in nodejs, so I decide to test by closing the connection.**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
dbConnect.end();
```

Comment: I got an error after using this. "(node:7976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: dbConnect.end is not a function"